# How to create an object with an unknown number of arguments in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Well, I have to create an object that represents an polynom af any size:

```
var polynom = function() {
    //code ...
};
p1 = polynom(1,6,3,4); // 1x^6 + 3x^4
p2 = polynom(3,5,2,1,7,3); // 3x^5 + 2x^1 + 7x^3
```

what I want to do is write a method that return an array with all these arguments. I read a little about this.arguments, so I write something like that:

```
var polynom = function() {

    getArguments = function() {
    array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.arguments.size; i++) array.push(this.arguments[i]);
    return array;
  }
};

const p1 = new polynom(3,2);
console.log(p1.getArguments());
```

and I get this message

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getArguments' of undefined
    at eval:14:16
    at eval
    at new Promise
```

I'm new at javascript so sorry if there's something wrong, but I would appreciate some help to write this method.

Comment: `this.getArguments = ...`!

Comment: `const p1 = new polynom(3,2);` ... your `polynom` object does nothing with it's arguments, so, they're lost

Comment: you just write "this" before all the function? I did this but still the same error

Comment: A simpler way to get function arguments as an array: `[].prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Comment: @JaromandaX you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Yep. Use `arguments` in the constructor itself

Comment: @fubar ... either `[].slice.call` or `Array.prototype.slice.call` :p because [].prototype is undefined

Comment: @JaromandaX - my bad. I started writing the full prototype chain, and changed my mind before I posted. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Rest arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

```js
var polynom = function(...args) {
  this.getArguments = function() {
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {array.push(args[i]);};
    return array;
  }
};

const p1 = new polynom(3,2);
console.log(p1.getArguments());
```

Comment: You don't need the loop. The `args` is already an Array. Just return it, or `.slice()` it if you want a shallow copy.

Comment: `...` isn't available in all browsers (I'm calling you out, Internet Exploder)

Comment: But @rockstar is right, args is already an array, thank you too man.

Comment: if you're going to use ES2016+ ... use all of it `class polynom {
    constructor(...args) {
        this.args = args;
    }
    getArguments() {
        return this.args;
    }
};`

Comment: for Internet Exploder - `function polynom() {
    this.args = [].slice.call(arguments);
}
polynom.prototype.getArguments = function() {
    return this.args;
};` - this is all JavaScript 101 stuff!

Comment: you know how can I call this function without using "new" when creating the object p1?

Comment: @JoséRamon you should ask a separate question for that